# How to disable SSD cache in SSHD drive?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, hybrid-storage

I'm using Lenovo B5400 [59-428850] laptop with **500GB HDD + 8GB SSD hybrid drive** and I have some issues with boot process recently. System freezes during startup (in 30-50% cases) with 3 short beep signals (which means "System initialization failure" as far as I know). When system is started from hibernation, there is no problem at all.

I have strong suspicion that the source of the problem is dying SSD part of my hard drive. Unfortunately, there seems to be no access to that part of the storage. It works as a cache (stores files identified as accessed during startup to boost up system loading). It is managed by a internal SSHD drivers and seems to be non-accessible and system-independent.

Is there any way to **disable SSD component** in such a hybrid drive?
Any idea how to check the SSD component separately for errors?

Comment: No;  there is no way to disable it.  All HDDs have a cache, your hybrid HDD, just has a very large cache.  But your problems indicate a problem with the HDD itself, not just the cache, which is unlikely to have worn out.

Comment: It's unlikely that the SSD part of your hard drive is dying. Far more likely is Microsoft's fast-startup (aka. hybrid boot) feature. Disable that and see how you go: http://www.wintips.org/how-to-turn-off-fast-startup-in-windows-10-8-and-8-1/

Comment: @misha256 - not this time, Linux here ;)

Comment: @kurp Haha, awesome. Go Linux! Clearly I should have had more coffee yesterday because, re-reading your question, "three beeps" IMO is the BIOS throwing a tantrum during POST. Can you confirm whether those beeps happen *before* OS loading, or *during* OS loading?

Comment: @misha256: It's during OS loading. After BIOS, GRUB stages. When Linux Mint splash screen is displayed. And last 3-5 starts was fine. This problem comes and goes...